# component file not found error in UI5 application

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am getting the attached error when loading the UI5 application. My project name is 'NPAWRMA' and i am getting error as NPAWRMA.Component is not found.
Please find the attached code for Component.js file.

Can you please help me in fixing this issue.

Regards,
Ajay

```js
header.view.xml

<mvc:View controllerName="NPAWRMA.controller.header" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
 displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
 <App id="idAppControl">
  <pages>
   <Page title="NPAW RMA Report">
    <content>
     <Table id="table" growing="true" items="{/npirev}">
      <columns>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label01}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label02}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label03}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label04}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label05}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label06}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label07}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label08}"/>
       </Column>
       <Column>
        <Text text="{Labels>/Labels1/Label09}"/>
       </Column>
      </columns>
      <items>
       <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="onPress">
        <Text text="{odata>Ktext}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
        <Text text="{odata>Netwr}"/>
       </ColumnListItem>
      </items>
     </Table>
    </content>
   </Page>
  </pages>
 </App>
</mvc:View>
```

```js
Manifest.json

{
 "_version": "1.7.0",
 "sap.app": {
  "id": "NPAWRMA",
  "type": "application",
  "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
  "applicationVersion": {
   "version": "1.0.0"
  },
  "dataSources": {
   "odataService": {
    "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZRMA_REV_SRV/",
    "type": "OData",
    "settings": {
     "odataVersion": "2.0",
     "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
    }
   }
  },

  "title": "{{appTitle}}",
  "description": "{{appDescription}}",
  "sourceTemplate": {
   "id": "ui5template.basicSAPUI5ApplicationProject",
   "version": "1.40.12"
  }
 },

 "sap.ui": {
  "technology": "UI5",
  "icons": {
   "icon": "",
   "favIcon": "",
   "phone": "",
   "phone@2": "",
   "tablet": "",
   "tablet@2": ""
  },
  "deviceTypes": {
   "desktop": true,
   "tablet": true,
   "phone": true
  },
  "supportedThemes": [
   "sap_hcb",
   "sap_belize"

  ]
 },

 "sap.ui5": {
  "rootView": {
   "viewName": "NPAWRMA.view.header",
   "type": "XML"
  },
  "dependencies": {
   "minUI5Version": "1.30.0",
   "libs": {
    "sap.ui.core": {},
    "sap.m": {},
    "sap.ui.layout": {},
    "sap.ushell": {},
    "sap.collaboration": {},
    "sap.ui.comp": {},
    "sap.uxap": {}
   }
  },
  "contentDensities": {
   "compact": true,
   "cozy": true
  },
  "models": {
   "i18n": {
    "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
    "settings": {
     "bundleName": "NPAWRMA.i18n.i18n"
    }
   },
  "odata": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel",
        "dataSource": "odataService",
        "preload": true
      }
  },
  "resources": {
   "css": [{
    "uri": "css/style.css"
   }]
  },

  "routing": {
   "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "viewPath": "NPAWRMA.view",
    "controlId": "idAppControl",
    "controlAggregation": "pages",
       "async": true
   },
  
   "routes": [{
    "name": "r1",
    "pattern": "",
    "target": "t1"
   }, {
    "name": "r2",
    "pattern": "page2/{noti}",
    "target": "t2"
   }],
   "targets": {
    "t1": {
     "viewName": "header",
     "viewId": "idhead",
     "viewLevel": 1
    },
    "t2": {
     "viewName": "item",
     "viewId": "iditem",
     "viewLevel": 2
    }
   }
  }
 },
    "sap.platform.abap": {
        "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZRMA_REV_SRV",
        "_version": "1.1.0"
    }
}
```

```js
Component.js

sap.ui.define([
 "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
 "sap/ui/Device",
 "NPAWRMA/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
 "use strict";

 return UIComponent.extend("NPAWRMA.Component", {

  metadata: {
   manifest: "json"
  },

  /**
   * The component is initialized by UI5 automatically during the startup of the app and calls the init method once.
   * @public
   * @override
   */
  init: function() {
   //"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *.local.com";
   //"Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-KEY";

   // call the base component's init function
   var url = "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZRMA_REV_SRV";
   var odata = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(url, {
    json: true
   });
   this.setModel(odata, "odata"); // call the base component's init function

   UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

   // set the device model
   this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");
   
   // enable routing
   this.getRouter().initialize();
  }
 });
});
```

Attached Manifest.json and header.view.xml file for reference.

Comment: Isn’t that just the flexibility service? Is it breaking something?

Comment: Hi Ethan,,,how to know that we can ignore this error?...because i not able to see the table header.

Comment: Hi Ajay - I don't see a table defined anywhere in what you've shared. You'll have to share all the parts of the code that create the table in order to diagnose any problem with it.

Comment: is the SICF node `sap/bc/lrep/flex/..` activated?

Comment: Hi Marc...in SICF i can see only upto sap/bc/lrep. But no folder after that.Can you please tell me how to actvate the required service.

Comment: Hi Ethan..I have added my table view and manifest file for reference.